# Create browser fingerprint

Tags: javascript

I wish to create a browser fingerprint for every user on my website.
I do this by iterating trough winow.screen window.navigator object properties. I copy them to an object.

The problem is at window.navigator.plugins when I use JSON.stringify I don't get the filename of plugins installed. The property is there but somehow is not serialized using JSON.stringify.

The object is like this window.navigator.plugins[0].filename

How can I get all object content using stringify ?!

Answer (score 2):

This will turn it into an array and extract only the filename from there, which can then be stringified properly:

```
[].slice.call(navigator.plugins).map(function(plugin){return plugin.filename})
JSON.stringify([].slice.call(navigator.plugins).map(function(plugin){return plugin.filename}))
```

Answer (score 0):

This `window.navigator.plugins` is not normal JSON object.
This is circular JSON which contains `self` value. This can't be converted to `String` by `JSON.stringfy()`

Here is the reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value

We can use this [flattted](https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted#flatted) to convert a string or parse.